# SQL server sum and count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I've got two  tables:

orders:

1. orderId
2. orderTotal
3. state

orderStatesHistory

1. id
2. orderId
3. stateId

I need to display get to display results like this.

[image]

Right now my code is this, I'm using SQL Server

```html
WITH totalOrders AS
  (
    SELECT orders.state, COUNT(1) AS counter, SUM(orders.orderTotal) AS total
    FROM orders
    CROSS APPLY
    (
      SELECT orderId, currentDateTime FROM orderStatesHistory
      WHERE (orderStatesHistory.stateId = 1 OR orderStatesHistory.stateId = 3)
      AND NULLIF(orderStatesHistory.subStateId, 0) IS NULL
      AND orderStatesHistory.currentDateTime BETWEEN '2015-07-28 00:00:00' AND '2015-08-04 00:00:00'      
      AND orders.id = orderStatesHistory.orderId
    ) AS statesHistory
    WHERE orders.state IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    AND orders.documentType = 1
    GROUP BY orders.state
  )
  SELECT 9999 AS state, SUM(counter) AS counter, SUM(total) AS total
    FROM totalOrders

  UNION
    
  SELECT state, counter, total
  FROM totalOrders
```

Problem is somehow, registries in orderStatesHistory might be duplicated, and I only want to use each orderId once in "count()" and "sum()"

I've been struggling pretty hard, not sure if i'll be able to do it all with SQL, maybe some genius helps me out, if not I'll do it throught the software.

NOTE: When I do count() and sum(), I want to only use one time each orderId, if they are duplicated i don't want to count them.

Any help is apreciated, even someone saying it is imposible.

PD: I'm willing to use JOINS if necesary, no need to use SQL server specific language.

UPDATE 1:

Data in orderStatesHistory
[image]

Data in orders
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using a `JOIN` and `DISTINCT` instead of a `CROSS APPLY`. If you could post some sample data, it would help in verifying.

```html
WITH totalOrders AS
  (
    SELECT orders.state, COUNT(1) AS counter, SUM(orders.orderTotal) AS total
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT orderId FROM orderStatesHistory
      WHERE (orderStatesHistory.stateId = 1 OR orderStatesHistory.stateId = 3)
      AND NULLIF(orderStatesHistory.subStateId, 0) IS NULL
      AND orderStatesHistory.currentDateTime BETWEEN '2015-07-28 00:00:00' AND '2015-08-04 00:00:00'
    ) AS statesHistory
    ON orders.id = statesHistory.orderId
    WHERE orders.state IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    AND orders.documentType = 1
    GROUP BY orders.state
  )
  SELECT 9999 AS state, SUM(counter) AS counter, SUM(total) AS total
    FROM totalOrders

  UNION
    
  SELECT state, counter, total
  FROM totalOrders
```

Comment: Nope, still the same, my query has to group by stateId from the table orderStatesHistory and then count(1) and sum(orderTotal) from orders table only registries with diferent orderId.

Thanks anyway

Comment: If you could script out some of that sample data, that would help me debug this a little quicker.

Comment: @Borjante see updated answer.  Took out currentDateTime from subquery since it is not being used in the outer query.